# How to implement verifying existing username

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am newbie in iOS with swift. What I need to do right now is that I have a textfield for user to enter his/er username. And once he clicks the other textfields, say password section, the application will automatically check whether this name exists or not and display a "V" or "X" image in a imageView. But I don't know how to do that or what method or action I should deal with. In Android, I could detect the focus of that textfield.Once the textfield loses the focus and if the text isn't empty, I can retrieve the text and request to my server to verify whether it exists or not. In iOS, I'm totally confused how to detect this, and is this related with first responder? Thx for advice in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextFieldDelegates.

```
class XXX : YOURCONTROLLER, UITextFieldDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.PASSCODE.delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     if textField == PASSCODE {
          //update stuffs
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx! That's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you generally create the interface in Interface Builder (a graphical tool you can use to place UI elements on screen and define many of their properties), and then you link them to your code using what's called IBOutlets/IBActions.
The code your link those elements to is often the view controller ; the view controller is the object that is responsible for managing a view and the events it receives.

[image]
To make an IBOutlet, go to your interface builder file (1), select the view controller you are interested by (2, for you it will be the one it which your form is present) open the assistant editor (3), the assistant editor should show to code corresponding to your view controller. Then control drag to the inside of your view controller class definition (4).

[image]
Once you do that there will be a little "popup" asking you wether you want an outlet or an action (5), if you just want a reference to the given UI object, then select an outlet.
If the object does an action (for example a button) and you want a method to be called when this action occurs, then you would choose action.

From there this should be pretty straightforward, what I would do would be to make an outlet to the textfield containing the password, and an action for the "Send/Connect" button, whether the method linked to this event would be called, I would check if the password is right or wrong.

EDIT : Maybe I added to much details and you already know a lot about what I told you, but when beginning, those things aren't always that much easy.

Comment: Thx! I knew the basic knowledge about how to connect UI with classes and so on. What I need only is how to trigger the TextFieldEndEditing